# React Native NetInfo addEventListener fires at the very beginning

Tags: react-native

I would like to fire my event listener when I am offline/online and I have already started my app, and then when I get online/offline my event should fire that while using the app.

But, It fires when my app initializes.

```
class App extends Component {
    handleFirstConnectivityChange(isConnected) {
        console.log('Then, is ' + (isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline'));
        NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
            'connectionChange',
            this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
        );
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
            console.log('First, is ' + (isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline'));
        });

        NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
            'connectionChange',
            this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
        );
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <MenuProvider>
                <RootNavigator />
                <PushController/>
            </MenuProvider>
        );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then((isConnected) => {
     console.log('First, is ' + (isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline'));

     NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
      'connectionChange',
      this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
   );
});
```

Putting

> addEventListener

into

> NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then

resolves the issue. Now it only calls once while using the app

Answer (score 0):

in your handler function

```
   handleFirstConnectivityChange(isConnected) {
        console.log('Then, is ' + (isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline'));
        NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
            'connectionChange',
            this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
        );
    }
```

your are removing the listener when it first time calls so it not listening anymore. Either you are online or offline first time it gets called anyway.